# 2-Step Authentication using Email Instead of SMS

Tags: php, validation, email, authentication, admin

How would I go about protecting admin or user accounts on my site(s) from brute-force password cracking attempts, using 2-step (a.k.a. 2-factor) authentication? I really want to use SMS 2-Step authentication for my site(s), but I can't find a free provider that is willing to let me send SMS text messages to my [or my customers] cellphones to authenticate access nor an API to do so automatically.

So now I just want to make sure nobody can get into the admin section of my site by sending me an email with a temporary (active for only about 5-10 minutes) code to my private Yahoo or Google email address (hidden in a PHP file), that both *already* implement SMS two-step authentication, every time I get my username and password correct at the admin login page.

Email identity verification at user login for normal users would be too cumbersome and annoying to implement for every member of my site. SMS would be too, if there were no way to disable it. However I don't mind going to my email to get the code at every admin login attempt if it means extra security for my site(s).

I'm looking [specifically] for some type of PHP session-based code that I can put at the top of my admin pages, and a random code generator to create and send the code to my email for the admin login. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to try adding some line breaks to your question, as well as some of the code you've tried.

Comment: 2-step auth isn't the only way to prevent brute force attacks. If an user tries to log in x amount of times within x amount of seconds force a timeout before the server will process the request.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - I don't want to do that, because wouldn't they be able to try again by just clearing their cookies? I think more details about my specific site would be useful. I'm using a script as a foundation for my site. I have built heavily upon it, and changed many things about how it works but you can find the base script here: [link](http://www.milliondollarscript.com/) .

Comment: No, clearing their cookies/changing their ip/changing computers won't allow them to try again if you force the timeout on the server side. Either in the database create a table for logins. Then on every login select all the logins that have occured in the past 1 hour. if there are x amount return an error saying please try again in x amount of seconds.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - Can you cook up some code for that? Will I need to create a new DB? I'm not that skilled [yet] in programming communication between PHP and MYSQL DB's. Sorry, I was hoping for an easier to implement (cut-and-paste) solution in PHP that would require slight modification to fit my circumstance and needs.

Comment: I can probably write a small general example. But this would be heavily based on your current login process. 
Also you don't need a new database just a new table in the database

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - Let's scratch that method. All a hacker has to do is adjust his hacking program to allow for the extra waiting periods, and it's so much more risky and fallible that way. I want to stick to the original purpose for the question (also to help others who find this question): I want to find a way (PHP snippet, script, etc.) to have a time-sensitive random code generated and sent to my secure Yahoo or Gmail, after I get the initial admin login credentials correct.

Comment: Also, I want to share my actual site, so that the helpful people here at SO can see what I'm dealing with, but given what I've disclosed about its insecure nature, I think that would be really stupid, and in essence saying "please, hack me", so if you show me a way to upload some of my PHP pages (in which i could exclude sensitive information from), that would be great. I am still new to SO, and still learning my way around.